# Measures with bounded total variation norm compact in $M(X)$?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, compactness

Let $X$ be a separable, metric, compact space. (e.g. an interval in $\mathbb{R}$ like $[0,10]$).

Let $M(X)$ be the set of all finite signed measures over $X$ with weak-*-topology (in probability theory also called weak-topology), e.g. dual to bounded continuous functions over $X$.

Then define $A= \left\{ 
\mu \in M(X) : |\mu|(X) \leq a
\right\}$ for $a>0$, and $|\mu|(X)$ the total variation norm.

Now my question:

Is the set $A$ compact in $M(X)$ ?

Comment: Yes. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/479332/prokhorovs-theorem-for-finite-signed-measures provides a reference.

Comment: This reference there leads only to sequential compactness and not to compactness (because $M(X)$ is not metrizable)... Hence I think it does not answer this question here...

Comment: "e.g. dual to bounded continuous functions over $X$" --> the use of "e.g." suggests that you can also choose a different predual, but the weak-$*$ topology depends on the chosen predual! So "e.g." is not what you want here.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The Banach-Alaoglu theorem states that the unit ball of the dual of any Banach space is weak$^*$-compact and $M(X)$ equipped with the total variation norm is nothing but the dual of $C(X)$. By scaling the result holds for any $a>0$.